# How to call a Stored Procedure to Open Ref Cursors with Different Queries

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

I have a homework assignment that wants me use a stored procedure with cursors to return queries from multiple tables. The query changes based on an input value that's a number, and the queries can be from single tables or joins on multiple tables depending on the number the user running the anon block selects. I found a perfect example of what I need in the oracle docs online, but there's no anonymous block in the docs that explains how this procedure is called.

Have searched on stack overflow, google and my plsql book from Joan Casteel but most anon blocks I've found return queries from only one table. I have gotten an anonymous block to run with a similar procedure as long as it doesn't query multiple tables, and my anon block only ran when it was returning a single variable and not a table of multiple columns.

This is the code from the oracle doc:

```
CREATE PACKAGE admin_data AS
   TYPE gencurtyp IS REF CURSOR;
   PROCEDURE open_cv (generic_cv IN OUT gencurtyp, choice INT);
END admin_data;
/
CREATE PACKAGE BODY admin_data AS
  PROCEDURE open_cv (generic_cv IN OUT gencurtyp, choice INT) IS
  BEGIN
  IF choice = 1 THEN
     OPEN generic_cv FOR SELECT * FROM employees;
  ELSIF choice = 2 THEN
     OPEN generic_cv FOR SELECT * FROM departments;
  ELSIF choice = 3 THEN
     OPEN generic_cv FOR SELECT * FROM jobs;
  END IF;
END;
```

END admin_data;
   /

I would post my homework assignment but I think it's better that I understand an example and try to apply it. How would you write the anonymous block?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're so focused on an anonymous block; although it can be done that way, your assignment says to use a stored procedure (which - I presume - can be a function as well); moreover, a procedure makes more sense.

Anyway, here's a SQL*Plus example which shows how to do that:

```
SQL> set pagesize 100
SQL> set verify off
SQL>
SQL> var choice number;
SQL> var rc refcursor;
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    if &&choice = 1 then
  3       open :rc for select * from dept;
  4    elsif &&choice = 2 then
  5       open :rc for select * From bonus;
  6    elsif &&choice = 3 then
  7       open :rc for select d.dname, e.ename, e.job
  8                    from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno;
  9    end if;
 10  end;
 11  /
Enter value for choice: 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :rc

ENAME      JOB              SAL       COMM
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT       1000        100

SQL> undefine choice
SQL> /
Enter value for choice: 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :rc

DNAME                ENAME      JOB
-------------------- ---------- ---------
ACCOUNTING           CLARK      MANAGER
ACCOUNTING           KING       PRESIDENT
ACCOUNTING           MILLER     CLERK
RESEARCH             JONES      MANAGER
RESEARCH             FORD       ANALYST
RESEARCH             ADAMS      CLERK
RESEARCH             SMITH      CLERK
RESEARCH             SCOTT      ANALYST
SALES                WARD       SALESMAN
SALES                TURNER     SALESMAN
SALES                ALLEN      SALESMAN
SALES                JAMES      CLERK
SALES                BLAKE      MANAGER
SALES                MARTIN     SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Option which uses a function looks like this; as you can see, it is almost the same as in the previous example.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_choice in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    if par_choice = 1 then
  7       open rc for select * from dept;
  8    elsif par_choice = 2 then
  9       open rc for select * From bonus;
 10    elsif par_choice = 3 then
 11       open rc for select d.dname, e.ename, e.job
 12                    from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno;
 13    end if;
 14
 15    return rc;
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(2) from dual;

F_TEST(2)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME      JOB              SAL       COMM
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT       1000        100


SQL> select f_test(1) from dual;

F_TEST(1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON


SQL>
```

Comment: The homework objective is to call the stored procedure using a PL/SQL anonymous block and is graded in part on conforming to the homework requirements. The professor is not copying the stored procedure to the command line or calling it with a SELECT statement, but executing the anonymous block